# Is it possible to build a blog with html only?

Tags: html, azure, blogs, azure-storage

I want to build a blog with only HTML, meaning that no database, no PHP, just plain HTML.
Is it possible to do that?

It may be weird, but I just want to build a very simple blog that just require 2 functions:

- create new post
- comment

It will be hosted in Azure Blob, so no PHP, no database.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want people to be able to comment: no. Otherwise: yes.

Comment: You're looking for a static website generator, I suggest to review the big list http://iwantmyname.com/blog/2011/02/list-static-website-generators.html

Comment: @XepterX css & javascript is ok. Anything can be done with only azure blob will do.

Comment: @Mischa Thanks. How's the no comment version? Can you tell me more?

Comment: @Joannes Vermorel Thanks a lot! I will try it now. Will tell you my result soon :)

Comment: You would be able to post comments provided that the Javascript was able to write to Windows Azure Storage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course. People did it in 1996 all the time.

**Create new post:**

- Open blog.html in notepad.
- Code new blog post above the latest
- Save blog.html, upload.

**Comment:**

- "Woah, this blog is epic."

Comment: Okay, by modifying the html directly,and use a mail service on a remote host to mail the comments to the owner of the blog, and then he added them in the html via his notepad editor ?

Answer (score 1):

Well I guess its not a good idea but if you have to do this you'll have to work a few things manually.

You will

1. Create blog posts manually using any HTML editor and upload updated HTML pages to server manually.
2. For comments you can create a "send to email" form (http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/forms.php) and receive comments in email. After user posts comments you can show a message saying the comment is sent for moderation.
3. After you receive a comment in email you'll have to update it in HTML manually.

Javascript or Jquery can be used for some enhancements in the process. Hope this works. :)

Comment: For the "update html manually" he could create a blog program which downloads the html, adds a new blog post from a template and adds it to the html and finally upload it again :)

Comment: @sjums yes thats like adding more sugar :)

Comment: Since the OP mentioned working with Windows Azure and blobs: You'd actually want to upload the new blog post to a blob container, then modify the main html file to have a url link to that blog post.

Answer (score 0):

No.

How do you save the posts? Only serverside scripting will make this possible.

Comment: It's called static HTML files. He didn't say he wanted a CMS.

Comment: It stands for Create More Static [html]

Comment: @Kai Feng Chew : do you want a blogspot style blog, with cms , so you can add posts online, or just a static site you download, update the html manually and upload again ?